# how connect to IoT devices with python

Tags: python, django, sockets, iot, raspberry-pi4

I have 300 sensors in a wide site and every 200 ms I have to send a request to them to get data 
and sensors reply at max 100 ms
sensors manufacturer programmed the sensors to answer requests on socket(TCP/IP) only
and I want to make a dashboard for monitor sensors status by python and Django  and  run it on raspberry pi 4(4 G Ram)

is it possible?
how I connect to 150 sensors at the same moment (multi-thread? or another way)
and raspberry pi 4 can handle this project?

Comment: Have you looked into https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: @Ben 
yes I know how to work with it
bu I didn't understand what you mean